Xcode & Flutter IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET and using the first of multiple matching destinations
I just updated my macos to Sequoia 15 and subsequently had to update Xcode to 16.0. For my build settings, I've set my IOS target to 15.0 and my Xcode project target to 12.0.
My initial error was the IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET being set to versions before the accepted 12.0-18.09. I think i fixed this with
config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '15.0'

Now im getting the following error:
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B345A905-A676-402C-9E03-9488424DDF94, OS:18.0,
    name:iPhone 16 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B345A905-A676-402C-9E03-9488424DDF94, OS:18.0,
    name:iPhone 16 Plus }
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/tr/yb7b1tfj3674zn3rlk57mf6r0000gn/T/flutter_tools.DhBrOU/flutt
        er_ios_build_temp_dirmncYjc/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    clang: error: unsupported option '-G' for target
    'x86_64-apple-ios15.0-simulator'
    clang: error: unsupported option '-G' for target

I'e also updated cocoapods but it looks like my packages are unable to install and Pods-Runner has an error with nearly every package. For example:
ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = YES
CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER = NO
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AppAuth" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/BoringSSL-GRPC" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseAppCheckInterop" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseAuth" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseAuthInterop" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseCore" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseCoreExtension" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseCoreInternal" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseFirestore" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseFirestoreInternal" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseSharedSwift" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseStorage" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GTMAppAuth" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GTMSessionFetcher" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleSignIn" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleUtilities"

Hers flutter doctor :
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on macOS 15.0 24A335 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.93.1)
[✓] Connected device (5 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!


The fact that there are multiple destinations with the same id is suspicious. I'd delete all the Xcode simulator runtimes and re-install them.
If that doesn't solve it, then try the workaround at https://github.com/FlutterFlow/flutterflow-issues/issues/3834#issuecomment-2357030268. Whatever works for you, don't forget to post it as an answer for the community.

Hey Spencer, were you able to fix the issue?
